# Xubuntu 12.04 or Xubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: xubuntu, system-requirements

My computer, a HP d260 MT brand machine has the following specs:

- Pentium 4 processor @3.0 Ghz
- On-board Intel 82865G graphics controller
- 1 GB RAM
  It is bios supported
  Can anyone tell me should I choose Xubuntu 12.04 or Xubuntu 12.04.2
  Thank you
  My computer has xp and ubuntu 10.04 installed.And hid the grub with windows as default and i am not able to access ubuntu.

Comment: why not 13.04, get all the bells and whistles :) take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Comment: i thought that xubuntu 12.04.2 is for uefi and xubuntu 12.04 is for bios

Comment: i am not able to boot into xubuntu 12.04.2 live cd which i burned myself. Is it because i have ubuntu 10.04 installed already.Burning cd was successful at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are the same, just different point releases.   The point releases and dates are: 12.04.1 (23 August 2012), 12.04.2 (14 February 2013), 12.04.3 (22 August 2013) and 12.04.4 (24 January 2014).

Now that being said, you can download and install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/).  I just installed it on a Celeron with 1GB RAM, and I love it.  Its quick, and snappy.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: but when i used xubuntu 12.04.2 its not booting into installer from cd\

Comment: Why did accept, and unaccept the answer?  How did you burn the CD?  What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: no error message i got at the time of burning the live cd

Comment: sorry i unaccepted as i still did not get answer

Comment: You said xubuntu 12.04.2 its not booting into installer.  What is it doing?  Plus your question was which one to choose, and not about the installation itself.

Comment: its only showing 'boot from cd:' and not responding can you help me please.

Comment: Try this: Do an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the ISO, and try creating a bootable USB using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: my bios is not supported for usb boot

Comment: Then do an MD5SUM, and try burning another CD at lower speed.  Where did you download the file from?

Comment: Xubuntu.org and i downloaded using torrent i did xubuntu 12.04.2 destop iso version for i386

Comment: I did an md5sum its same from ubuntu hash

Comment: Try downloading it from [Here](http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/precise/release/), and burn another CD.